# Subquery Postgres: two tables not directly related

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join

**plates**

| plate_id | date | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-12-2020 | 101 |
| 2 | 01-12-2020 | 202 |
| 3 | 02-12-2020 | 101 |
| 4 | 02-12-2020 | 202 |
| 5 | 02-12-2020 | 303 |

**production**

| order_id | date | product_id | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 01-12-2020 | 101 | 10.95 |
| 1002 | 01-12-2020 | 202 | 19.00 |
| 1003 | 02-12-2020 | 101 | 11.50 |
| 1004 | 02-12-2020 | 202 | 20.05 |
| 1005 | 02-12-2020 | 303 | 17.00 |

**the result of the query I need to get is:**

| plate_id | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 20.05 |

Their are not related with pk and fk,

each product can have more then one production cost.

I suppose that I need to create some subquery where to take into account always two columns: date and product_id

below query unfortunatelly gives an error

```
SELECT pl.plate_id, pr.cost
FROM plates pl
JOIN (select * from production pr where pr.date=pl.date and pr.product_id=pl.product_id)
WHERE pl.product_id = 4;
```

Comment: Why `20.05` instead of `19.00`? Are you ordering by latest date or highest cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a join on `product_id` and `date`:

```
select pl.plate_id, pr.cost
from plates pl
inner join production pr using (product_id, date)
where pl.plate_id = 4
```

Comment: in my real case I had to write:                                                                                             inner join mrp_production pr on (pr.product_id=pp.id, pr.date_planned_start::date=m.date) but I get following error:

argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type record

Comment: @kubaSpolsky. So: `inner join mrp_production pr on pr.product_id=pp.id and pr.date_planned_start::date=m.date`